# Blank page in WebView

Tags: swift, url, uiwebview, wkwebview, xcode9

I get a blank screen when I load the web page :(

```
if let url = self.postLink {
    print("Go to: \(url)")
    var newUrl = URL(string: url)
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: newUrl!)
    webView?.delegate = self
    webView?.scalesPageToFit = true
    webView?.loadRequest(urlRequest)
}
```

"Go to:" show correct url. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have initialised your `webView` object properly?

Comment: Did you pass valid web URL, initialise and inserted web view into view stack?

Comment: not sure :( any article as example? or code...